# Creating Process Template from FindDistribution

Tags: distributions

may i ask if anybody knew where i wrong please? Im stuck in this step.

I want to visualize Hidden Markov Model in which state from 2-20 is best with continuous  emission, but it need starting value distribution so i use Finddistribution on each state and get

```
WeibullDistribution[2.64963,314.42,7004.56],
MixtureDistribution[{0.357944,0.642056},{GammaDistribution[2554.78,2.70206],LogNormalDistribution[8.93958,0.0110951]}]}
```

I've found recently that i must input Process Template from it to work such as

```
WeibullDistribution[c,d],
MixtureDistribution[{e,f},{GammaDistribution[g,h],LogNormalDistribution[i,j]}]}
```

but i need it to loop approximately 400 times so i cant manually change the distribution parameter one by one by myself, i want to find a function that automaticly turn WeibullDistribution[25.113,6001.07,103.586] into WeibullDistribution[a,b], i have googling and nothing found, can anybody help me please?

[image: Estimated Process Error]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It is not too clear what you are wanting to do. Please show your full code otherwise it is very difficult for people to help you

Comment: To echo @Dunlop 's comment:  It is not clear what you want.  But here's a guess:  `WeibullDistribution[25.113, 6001.07, 103.586] /. 
 WeibullDistribution[aa_, bb_, cc_] -> WeibullDistribution[a, b, c]`.